# how to enable root access to remote when Configure mysql instance?

Tags: mysql

I created a batch file for silent install and configure mysql.

following:

```
msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.21.msi" /quiet INSTALLDIR="%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5"


 MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q "-lC:\mysql_install_log.txt" "-nMySQL Server 5.5" "-p%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5" -v5.5.21 "-t%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my-template.ini" "-c%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIXED ConnectionUsage=OLTP Port=3306 ServiceName=Mysql Charset=utf8 RootPassword=m117988m
```

how to enable root access to remote With MySQLInstanceConfige.exe in batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MySQL docs, there is none.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.html

And that makes sense because it only configures settings that don't need the database running.

- Creating a Service
- Creating/Modifying a my.ini file
- Configuring a Windows Firewall Exception
- Adding the install dir to the path Environment variable

However. You could use mysql.exe command line tool to script this after your instance is up and running:

```
mysql.exe -u root -pm117988 -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'm117988' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

or another way that does not add another user entry but configures the existing one to allow remote connections.

```
mysql.exe -u root -pm117988 -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '%' WHERE host = 'localhost' AND user = 'root';
```

You could even provide a sql file for setting up your database after installation.
That file could contain this command and even creating a database/tables/data for you.

```
mysql.exe -u root -pm117988 < post_install_script.sql
```

Comment: Windows Firewall Exception is not added from command line, only from GUI